# EE error "The page you requested was not found."

Tags: ee2, control-panel, admin.php

I just made a fresh EE install on one of my clients shared server,and after setting up permissions etc when I try to access admin.php file I get this error

"The page you requested was not found."

I am not able to debug it,is it some thing to do with server or is it a EE bug??

Cheers
Nisar

Comment: ...and the solution was?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a .htaccess configuration problem or verify the  path or you admin.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply,it got fixed and sorry that I was not able to reply here